# how to customise the toolbar for a flutter SelectableRegion

Tags: flutter, textselection, themedata

When text in a **SelectableRegion** widget is selected, the toolbar generated by **materialTextSelectionControls** has options for 'Copy' and 'SelectAll'. What is the best way to disable 'SelectAll' and how can the styling (in particular, text color) of the options be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, my answer to my question is to copy the relevant flutter files for the **SelectableRegion** widget and customise them to make a **MySelectableRegion**  widget.

But surely there is a better way?

For anyone wanting to do the same as me, the files I copied and am editing are

```html
flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/selectable_region.dart

flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_selection.dart 

flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_selection_toolbar.dart
```

Comment: **Update** Flutter (from version) 3.7 now has ContextMenuBuilder, making it a lot easier to customise the standard Context Menu items (Copy, Select All etc). More information [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868518/how-to-have-a-custom-context-menu-for-textfields-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868518/how-to-have-a-custom-context-menu-for-textfields-in-flutter). Thank you @Pouya